# Https error with prestashop homepage

Tags: https, prestashop

I have a problem. I activated https on my ecommerce website prestashop and made all the settings and the security lock appears on all pages of the site except the home page. voci the link of the site: https://ivoirehorloge.com/index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two CMS content on the right side of the page "Découvrez nos horloges" isn't using https for the two images :

```
http://ivoirehorloge.com/img/cms/4_1.jpg
http://ivoirehorloge.com/img/cms/5_1.jpg
```

If you look at your browser debug console, you will see a message like :

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://ivoirehorloge.com/index.php' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://ivoirehorloge.com/img/cms/5_1.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS."